# How to write the \columnwidth to an external file

Tags: write-file

Some figures in my LaTeX document I am generating with Python. Normally I manually check how wide my picture can be with `\showthe\columnwidth` and adjust the image width accordingly. (This whole is important for not resizing text labels)

Is there a way that I can write this to a file, so I can do this magically? The `\columnwidth` is always the same through my document, so it only has to be written once. It would be especially nice if the file is not rewritten when the value hasn't changed (good for my Makefile).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newdimen\tempcolwidth \tempcolwidth0pt
\newwrite\widthfile
\AtBeginDocument{\checkcolwidth}
\newcommand\checkcolwidth{%
        \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.width}{}{}%
        \ifdim\columnwidth=\tempcolwidth\else
                \openout\widthfile=\jobname.width
                \write\widthfile{\tempcolwidth=\the\columnwidth}%
                \closeout\widthfile
        \fi
}
\begin{document}
asdf
\end{document}
```

I should point out that if your file is called `foo.tex`, then this will produce a file called `foo.width` which contains the line `\tempcolwidth =...pt` where the `...` is the actual width of the column. If after reading in the file, `\columnwidth` and `\tempcolwidth` agree, then the file is not written. Otherwise, the file is opened and the value of the column width written out.

Comment: @Peter: One thing to keep in mind is that TeX uses printer's points which are 72.27pt to 1 inch. Postscript and many other desktop software use 72pt to 1 inch. (TeX supports this latter unit, but calls it a big point. That is 72.27pt = 72bp = 1in.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I knew it actually (and was already using that measure) but it is probably very useful for anyone browsing by this question.